# I can't seem to play an audio file in my C# .NET Windows Form programm

Tags: c#, .net, wav, windows-forms-designer, pcm

I place my audio file called MouseClick.wav under my resources folder and I have a function in code to play it.

```
private void playSimpleSound()
{
    SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.MouseClick);
    simpleSound.Play();
}
```

However, when I run the programm:

```
    private void numPad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //my lines of code

    playSimpleSound();
}
```

I keep getting the error messages:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dllAn unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dllSound API only supports playing PCM wave files.
```

Then when I convert my MouseClick.wav file to PCM by using those online converter tools, I get another error message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dllAn unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dllThe file located at C:\blank\blank\blank\42ad11c67636a47fd5ec0fc5dde8cc55.pcm is not a valid wave file.
```

Please advice me, I have no idea what to do. I have tried using other wav file. I tried putting my wav file at other locations.

Comment: You need a .wav file whose content is encoded in pcm.

Answer (score 0):

SoundPlayer class has some limitation. Have you tried or checked any other .NET class or libraries?

Here is an example with NAudio. Use nugget to install NAudio.

```
using NAudio.Wave;
private void playSimpleSound()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.MouseClick))
    {
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(stream))
        {
            using (var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent())
            {
                waveOut.Init(reader);
                waveOut.Play();
                while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have a small issue where there is an error on this line [using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.MouseClick))] where it says Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' to 'int' TestSound C:\blank\TestSound\TestSound\Form1.cs 29 Active